# Hive data loading using complex json structure

Tags: arrays, json, struct, hive, hdfs

I am trying to load an external table via a JSON file having free schema arrays and structures.

```
create external table longtimedata_v4
(measurementPointName string,measurementPointId string,dataTypeId string,dataTypeName string,channels ARRAY<            struct<name:string,unit:string,dvalues:ARRAY<struct<atimedt:string,dvalue:string>>>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/warehouse/tablespace/external/hive/longtimedata'
```

```
{
    "measurementPointName": "Saab Scania, BBY2908, Sibbhult",
    "measurementPointId": 35,
    "dataTypeId": 1,
    "dataTypeName": "Voltage",
    "channels": [
        {
            "name": "U1 RMS",
            "unit": "V",
            "values": [
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T00:00:00Z",
                    "value": 21348.7695
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T00:10:00Z",
                    "value": 21342.7656
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T00:20:00Z",
                    "value": 21401.0957
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T00:30:00Z",
                    "value": 21415.2129
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T00:40:00Z",
                    "value": 21456.9062
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T00:50:00Z",
                    "value": 21501.541
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T01:00:00Z",
                    "value": 21527.4355
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T01:10:00Z",
                    "value": 21510.9512
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T01:20:00Z",
                    "value": 21436.2266
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T01:30:00Z",
                    "value": 21423.5176
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T01:40:00Z",
                    "value": 21415.6211
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T01:50:00Z",
                    "value": 21416.8008
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T02:00:00Z",
                    "value": 21460.6016
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T02:10:00Z",
                    "value": 21502.0195
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T02:20:00Z",
                    "value": 21405.748
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T02:30:00Z",
                    "value": 21321.9062
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T02:40:00Z",
                    "value": 21394.6074
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T02:50:00Z",
                    "value": 21392.3496
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T03:00:00Z",
                    "value": 21412.6875
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T03:10:00Z",
                    "value": 21320.5469
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T03:20:00Z",
                    "value": 21309.9746
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T03:30:00Z",
                    "value": 21229.5879
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T03:40:00Z",
                    "value": 21174.2891
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T03:50:00Z",
                    "value": 21100.6406
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T04:00:00Z",
                    "value": 21188.2207
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T04:10:00Z",
                    "value": 21146.1191
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T04:20:00Z",
                    "value": 21328.709
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T04:30:00Z",
                    "value": 21216.4844
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T04:40:00Z",
                    "value": 21104.7871
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T04:50:00Z",
                    "value": 21096.8398
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T05:00:00Z",
                    "value": 21147.1895
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T05:10:00Z",
                    "value": 21330.084
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T05:20:00Z",
                    "value": 21205.3965
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T05:30:00Z",
                    "value": 21116.1309
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T05:40:00Z",
                    "value": 21189.4648
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T05:50:00Z",
                    "value": 21113.0703
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T06:00:00Z",
                    "value": 21074.2109
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T06:10:00Z",
                    "value": 21093.0605
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T06:20:00Z",
                    "value": 21117.6934
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T06:30:00Z",
                    "value": 21087.8496
                },
                {
                    "time": "2022-10-24T06:40:00Z",
                    "value": 21077.8047
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My data got loaded, but not fully. The values array `channels.dvalues.atimedt` or `dvalue` is coming with `null` only.
I tried to load data via a load statement and other ways to populate the values array and underlying structure, but nothing worked out.

```
SELECT channels[5].name,channels.unit,channels[5].dvalues.atimedt
FROM observematare.longtimedata_v4;
```

```
U2 max  ["V","V","V","V","V","V","V","V","V","V","V","V"]   NULL
2   U2 max  ["V","V","V","V","V","V","V","V","V","V","V","V"]   NULL
```

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about bad code 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hive version mentioned in the question.

Also you have not mentioned the reason for using different column names in table for the field names in data file. I assume it because 'values' and 'time' are [reserved keywords](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Keywords,Non-reservedKeywordsandReservedKeywords).

The failure (values coming as null) reason - column names are different from the field names in json data

There are two ways to fix this issue

1. Change the field names in data file(s) to match the column names in `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` statement
2. Override the reserved keywords using back tick (`) - also known as `quoted identifiers`

About using Reserved keywords from [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual)

> Reserved keywords are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as described in [Supporting Quoted Identifiers in Column Names](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12618321/QuotedIdentifier.html) (version 0.13.0 and later, see HIVE-6013). Most of the keywords are reserved through HIVE-6617 in order to reduce the ambiguity in grammar (version 1.2.0 and later). There are two ways if the user still would like to use those reserved keywords as identifiers: (1) use quoted identifiers, (2) set hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false. (version 2.1.0 and earlier)

1. Changing the field names in data file

```
    {
        "measurementPointName": "Saab Scania, BBY2908, Sibbhult",
        "measurementPointId": 35,
        "dataTypeId": 1,
        "dataTypeName": "Voltage",
        "channels": [
            {
                "name": "U1 RMS",
                "unit": "V",
                "dvalues": [
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T00:00:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21348.7695
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T00:10:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21342.7656
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T00:20:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21401.0957
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T00:30:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21415.2129
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T00:40:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21456.9062
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T00:50:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21501.541
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T01:00:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21527.4355
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T01:10:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21510.9512
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T01:20:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21436.2266
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T01:30:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21423.5176
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T01:40:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21415.6211
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T01:50:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21416.8008
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T02:00:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21460.6016
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T02:10:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21502.0195
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T02:20:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21405.748
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T02:30:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21321.9062
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T02:40:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21394.6074
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T02:50:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21392.3496
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T03:00:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21412.6875
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T03:10:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21320.5469
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T03:20:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21309.9746
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T03:30:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21229.5879
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T03:40:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21174.2891
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T03:50:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21100.6406
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T04:00:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21188.2207
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T04:10:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21146.1191
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T04:20:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21328.709
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T04:30:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21216.4844
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T04:40:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21104.7871
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T04:50:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21096.8398
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T05:00:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21147.1895
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T05:10:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21330.084
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T05:20:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21205.3965
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T05:30:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21116.1309
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T05:40:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21189.4648
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T05:50:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21113.0703
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T06:00:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21074.2109
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T06:10:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21093.0605
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T06:20:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21117.6934
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T06:30:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21087.8496
                    },
                    {
                        "atimedt": "2022-10-24T06:40:00Z",
                        "dvalue": 21077.8047
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Select statement:

```
SELECT channels[0].name,channels.unit,channels[0].dvalues.atimedt FROM longtimedata_v4;
```

output:
Please note the column name

```
INFO  : OK
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  name   |  unit  |                      atimedt                       |
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| U1 RMS  | ["V"]  | ["2022-10-24T00:00:00Z","2022-10-24T00:10:00Z","2022-10-24T00:20:00Z","2022-10-24T00:30:00Z","2022-10-24T00:40:00Z","2022-10-24T00:50:00Z","2022-10-24T01:00:00Z","2022-10-24T01:10:00Z","2022-10-24T01:20:00Z","2022-10-24T01:30:00Z","2022-10-24T01:40:00Z","2022-10-24T01:50:00Z","2022-10-24T02:00:00Z","2022-10-24T02:10:00Z","2022-10-24T02:20:00Z","2022-10-24T02:30:00Z","2022-10-24T02:40:00Z","2022-10-24T02:50:00Z","2022-10-24T03:00:00Z","2022-10-24T03:10:00Z","2022-10-24T03:20:00Z","2022-10-24T03:30:00Z","2022-10-24T03:40:00Z","2022-10-24T03:50:00Z","2022-10-24T04:00:00Z","2022-10-24T04:10:00Z","2022-10-24T04:20:00Z","2022-10-24T04:30:00Z","2022-10-24T04:40:00Z","2022-10-24T04:50:00Z","2022-10-24T05:00:00Z","2022-10-24T05:10:00Z","2022-10-24T05:20:00Z","2022-10-24T05:30:00Z","2022-10-24T05:40:00Z","2022-10-24T05:50:00Z","2022-10-24T06:00:00Z","2022-10-24T06:10:00Z","2022-10-24T06:20:00Z","2022-10-24T06:30:00Z","2022-10-24T06:40:00Z"] |
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

2. Using quoted identifiers without changing column names while creating table

```
create external table longtimedata_v4 (
  measurementPointName string,
  measurementPointId string, 
  dataTypeId string,
  dataTypeName string, 
  channels ARRAY < struct < name : string, 
  unit : string, `values` : ARRAY < struct < `time` : string, 
  `value` : string >>>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/warehouse/tablespace/external/hive/longtimedata'
```

and while running select statement

```
SELECT channels[0].name,channels.unit,channels[0].`values`.`time` FROM longtimedata_v4;
```

output:
Please note the column name

```
INFO  : OK
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  name   |  unit  |                        time                        |
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| U1 RMS  | ["V"]  | ["2022-10-24T00:00:00Z","2022-10-24T00:10:00Z","2022-10-24T00:20:00Z","2022-10-24T00:30:00Z","2022-10-24T00:40:00Z","2022-10-24T00:50:00Z","2022-10-24T01:00:00Z","2022-10-24T01:10:00Z","2022-10-24T01:20:00Z","2022-10-24T01:30:00Z","2022-10-24T01:40:00Z","2022-10-24T01:50:00Z","2022-10-24T02:00:00Z","2022-10-24T02:10:00Z","2022-10-24T02:20:00Z","2022-10-24T02:30:00Z","2022-10-24T02:40:00Z","2022-10-24T02:50:00Z","2022-10-24T03:00:00Z","2022-10-24T03:10:00Z","2022-10-24T03:20:00Z","2022-10-24T03:30:00Z","2022-10-24T03:40:00Z","2022-10-24T03:50:00Z","2022-10-24T04:00:00Z","2022-10-24T04:10:00Z","2022-10-24T04:20:00Z","2022-10-24T04:30:00Z","2022-10-24T04:40:00Z","2022-10-24T04:50:00Z","2022-10-24T05:00:00Z","2022-10-24T05:10:00Z","2022-10-24T05:20:00Z","2022-10-24T05:30:00Z","2022-10-24T05:40:00Z","2022-10-24T05:50:00Z","2022-10-24T06:00:00Z","2022-10-24T06:10:00Z","2022-10-24T06:20:00Z","2022-10-24T06:30:00Z","2022-10-24T06:40:00Z"] |
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had tried at my end and it worked out well.